# Sensu: Registering client doesn't render keep alive warning after delay

Tags: sensu

When I create a Sensu client with the `POST /clients` API resource, it shows up in Uchiwa Dashboard, but I'm expecting the keep alive check to fail after 180 seconds by default because there is no actual Sensu client checking in.

How do I get the keep alive check to start failing?

Successfully adding `keepalive` to the subscriptions on register has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The Sensu server does not enable keepalive support for clients created via the API: https://github.com/sensu/sensu/blob/master/lib/sensu/server/process.rb#L476

```
  # Create a blank client (data) and add it to the client
  # registry. Only the client name is known, the other client
  # attributes must be updated via the API (POST /clients:client).
  # Dynamically created clients and those updated via the API will
  # have client keepalives disabled, `:keepalives` is set to
  # `false`.
```